# Redirecting domain from one web host to another

Tags: web-hosting, nameserver

First time I've ever had to redirect a domain from one web host to another. I'm not moving the domain registration as the domain is due to be renewed soon so don't want to risk any complications.

I've followed a detailed guide (http://www.thesitewizard.com/domain/point-domain-name-website.shtml) but is it just the NS addresses I need to change with that of the new web host?

Assuming the above is correct, would it be normal for this to take longer than 3 days to replicate globally?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a better way to have handled this is not to have changed the nameservers but simply to have changed the A record for the domain to be the IP address of the new web host. Then after the domain was renewed I would have changed the name servers to the new web host. Simpler and maybe less complicated.

But either way the change should have occurred worldwide by now unless the TTL is set to be greater then 72 hours or an intermediate server is caching the DNS longer then they should be. I'd check to see what the TTL is on your current server and if it is too high lower it. You still have to wait for it to expire on any server using the current TTL but this would ultimately speed things along.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I changed the A record to the new web host IP would I need to change the NS addresses back to what they were originally for it to work? Also for curiosity, what are the benefits of doing it this way?

Comment: Yes. Wherever your DNS is being hosted is where you need to change the A record. This way is just easier since it doesn't require moving your entire DNS. You just make one simple change. Then, when the domain name renewal is completed you can change the nameservers and be done with everything. Smaller changes make for (usually) smaller potential problems.